# Alert after fullscreen loading indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to display a fullscreen loading indicator while a request is being processed, in case request fails I might need to show an `Alert` with an error message immediately after the loading indicator is dismissed. Using a `Modal` to show the loading indicator works great on Android but unless a delay is added between dismissing the loading indicator and displaying the `Alert` iOS is going to hang up, [which is a known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471).

To solve this problem I've created a `View`-based `ProgressHUD` component to display loading indicator and put it as an `App` component child below all other components like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <AuthScreensStack />
  <ProgressHUD isLoading={false} />
</View>
```

The indicator itself works as expected and nothing hangs up. The problem I'm facing now is deciding how to toggle this `ProgressHUD`. I'm using `redux-saga` middleware so I could probably move the `ProgressHUD` outside of `App` component into something like a `LayoutComponent` and connect it to the `redux` storage to observe some `isLoading` flag, but that will require me to add an additional action to each of my sagas, which will make them messy. Ideally I would like to have control over the `ProgressHUD` in each of the screens that need to use it but rendering it in them will render below navigation bar / above tab bar. Is there a way, perhaps, to render a `View` over the entire app's window from within a screen that's displayed via `react-navigation`'s `navigator`? Any suggestions on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same challenge, I ended up using a ProgressHUDComponent and redux on the RootNavigation. The only way to render a `Model` on top of the `react-navigation header` is to use the `react-native Model component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using `redux-saga`, therefore you can chain it in the generators.

Considering an action such as `loadingOverlayVisible` triggers the `Modal` with the `loading indicator`

Either you can customize it in your saga where your firing it as

```
export function * submit() {
  try {
    yield put(loadingOverlayVisible(true)) // Modal Open
    const result = yield call(sampleApiCall)
    yield put(loadingOverlayVisible(false)) // Modal Close
    if(result && result.ok) {
       yield call(Alert.alert, 'Success', 'Success Response') // Alert Called
       //... Other stuff
    }
  } catch(ex) {
    yield call(Alert.alert, 'Success', 'Success Response') // Alert Called
  }
}
```

**OR**

Make a **separate middleware** for **ajax request interceptor** such as

```
export function * interceptor({url, params}) {
  try {
    yield put(loadingOverlayVisible(true)) // Modal Open
    const result = yield call(sampleApiCall)
    yield put(loadingOverlayVisible(false)) // Modal Close
  } catch(ex) { 
    throw ex // Either handle it here or in your other generators
  }
}
```